# Can anyone explain what this does: 'scanf("%d%*c",&n)'

Tags: c, scanf

i wrote a program for sorting the names of persons and i ask the user to give the number of persons that he want, and i stored it by using the below given line and it worked properly but, i din't understand the exact working of it. Can anyone explain it clearly?

```
scanf("%d%*c",&n);
```

Answer (score 5):

`%*c` is used to ignore the newline space or any other special characters.
So in this `scanf()` after entering the integer let's say you have a newline character in the buffer which will be gobbled by this `%*c`.

If you are not doing this and just after this scanf() if you have say

```
scanf("%c",&c); /* where c is a char */
```

Then you will be wondering that scanf() will never wait for you to enter a character instead it picks a newline character.

Comment: Of course, any white space, like a newline, can be consumed easily be placing a leading ' ' (space) in the format string.  This technique of always having a leading space in the format string will eliminate the need for any special handling of newline/tab /spaces sequences before the data of interest

Answer (score 0):

From here:
[scanf format string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scanf_format_string)

"An optional asterisk (*) right after the percent symbol denotes that the datum read by this format specifier is not to be stored in a variable. No argument behind the format string should be included for this dropped variable."

Comment: What is the output of the below code, neglect all the syntax errors.    #include <stdio.h>
    int main()
    {
     name="snow storm";
     name[5]="X";
     print(name);
     }

Answer (score 0):

`%*c` consumes the first `char` after the number (if there was one), be it a `'\n'`, some other white-space, alpha, *anything* including `'\0'`.

The `'*'` in `%*c`, directs `scanf()` to consume, but not save that `char`.

If no number was scanned via `"%d"`, maybe due to invalid input, then `"%*c"` does nothing as the preceding directive failed and `"%*c"` is not evaluated.

---

Using `scanf("%d%*c",&n);` has weak error handling.  For robust code, use a helper function.  Needless to say, this is far more complicated, but unfortunately C does not provide simple *and* robust reading of even simple things like `int`.

```
// Read 1 line, decode an `int`, save in *n
// Return EOF, 0:Invalid,  1:Success
int ReadInt(int *n) {
  int i;
  char buf[50];
  if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) == NULL) {
    return EOF;  // EOF occurred
  }
  char *endptr;  
  errno = 0;
  long num = strtol(buf, &endptr, 10);
  if (buf == endptr || (*endptr != '\n' && *endptr != '\0')) {
    return 0;  // failed conversion
  }
  if (errno || num < INT_MIN || num > INT_MAX) {
    return 0;  // range error
  }
  if (n != NULL) {
    *n = (int) num;
  }
  return 1;
}
```

Even this could be expanded to get for excessively long lines.

Comment: What is the output of the below code, neglect all the syntax errors. #include <stdio.h> int main() { name="snow storm"; name[5]="X"; print(name); } What will be the stored value of name if we print it?

Comment: @Prasanth Sai `name="snow storm"; name[5]="X";` --> Undefined behavior.   For more details,post this as a question.